# 'Replace' a char with an int in a string

Tags: c++, string, char, int

At first this seemed easy to do but I was mistaken. **I want to 'replace' a char (a variable) in a string with a int (value). But how?**

I tried replace() because I'm working with a string and it worked but it will not work if I wish to change the value of the variable again to another
value  because then the original variable will not be found. I have been struggling with this for the passed 2 days. Any help will be much appreciated on how to do this.

```
changeVar(string startingExpr, char var, int val)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < startingExpr.length(); i++)
    {
        if(startingExpr[i] == var)
        {
            cout << "I found x! Now to replace it!";
            startingExpr[i] = val;       //'Replace' x with 5, but x but how?
        }
    }
}
```

Your help on this one will be much appreciated.

J

Comment: If `val` is always a one-digit number, then `startingExpr[i] = val + '0';` should do the trick. Else you will need to insert, by formatting `val` as a decimal, its string representation at the given position. Google the documentation of `std::string`'s methods such as `find`, `remove`, `erase` and `insert`.

Comment: You're reinventing `std::replace`, but with output, which you could do with `std::replace_if`.

Comment: Instead of thinking this as modifying the original string, you could think of it as taking parts of original string (like parts before and after x here). Then combine the old parts you want with new parts (in this case value of int as string) to get the new string.

Comment: I hope you're aware of problems when the char occurs in the words of the sentence which you don't want to replace... Like in `"Here's the value for x: x!"` If the string is some kind of format string in your application, think of some special syntax like `"Here's the value for x: $(x)!"` to support arbitrary words in the sentence.

Comment: Regarding your original question, why do you face the problem described? As far as I can see, you pass the string *by value*, which means the function changes *a copy of it*. (I don't see what you do with it, as you don't show it in your code.) Summarized: please tell us more / add more code.

Comment: Your explanations are pretty muddled. One possible interpretation is that you want to replace a letter (the "variable") by a digit (the "value"). Like "X+1" becomes "3+1". Am I right ? Or maybe is it an identifier (several letters) by an integer (several digits) ?

Comment: @Daoust yes, that is precisely what I wish to do.  Your example with "X+1" becomes "3+1" is spot on.  I just dont know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to assign the number that is different from the ASCII character represntation. In ASCII table characters '0', '1' .. '9' goes one after another. So you can rewrite your code as:

```
startingExpr[i] = '0' + val;
```

But please aware that this is good for one character case only. If you need to replace multiple chars then your solution without need for a function is that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
  std::string a("SomeVar1"), b("SomeVar356");

  std::string::size_type index = std::string::npos;

  std::cout << "Before: " << a << std::endl;
  if ((index = a.rfind("1")) != std::string::npos)
    a.replace(index, 1, std::to_string(2));
  std::cout << "After: " << a << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Before: " << b << std::endl;
  if ((index = b.rfind("356")) != std::string::npos)
    b.replace(index, 3, std::to_string(673));
  std::cout << "After: " << b << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This is slightly optimized since it is using rfind (search from the end of the string).

P.S. As the comments suggested - you can use std::replace with reverse iterators and lambda for condition. Since it is available in C++11 I wrote a small example in universal style.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to replace the "variable" by the "value" as many times as you want, you should keep a copy of the original string and do the replacement from there only.

Another option is to undo the replacement (replace the value by the variable) and redo with another value, provided the undo can be done unambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear this problem wasted your more than 2 days. You shouldcarefully read a basic C++ textbook. As your problem is a very basic one. If you understand the arguments passing for function, you will sort this out!

More specific, you function is not wrong, but just did not deliver the results you want. Because your function using argument, which will make a copy of argument startingExpr inside the function body, when you make replacement using  "startingExpr[i] = val", the replacement is happened on the copy of startingExpr (which is a local variable just visible inside the function), your original startingExpr does change at all.

The solution is very simple, change argument passing with its reference, just add &, now the declaration your function should be: "changeVar(string startingExpr, char var, int val)"

Try the following code, which will demonstrate my explanation:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    //the original function which was reported had problem
    // This because the function using parameter not reference

    void changeVar(string startingExpr, char var, int val)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < startingExpr.length(); i++)
        {
            if(startingExpr[i] == var)
            {
                cout << "I found x! Now to replace it!(But the replace is happend inside the function, the original string is not changed!)"<<endl;
                startingExpr[i] = val;       //'Replace' x with 5, but x but how?
            }
        }
    }
    // updating using the reference 
    //void changeVar(string & startingExpr, char var, int val)
    void changeVar_refe(string & startingExpr, char var, int val)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < startingExpr.length(); i++)
        {
            if(startingExpr[i] == var)
            {
                cout << "I found x! Now to replace it!(Now using reference, the replace is happend inside the original string, which will be changed!)"<<endl;
                startingExpr[i] = val;       //'Replace' x with 5, but x but how?
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {

        //lets test the original function

        string my_name="Hi there, I am C++ taoism .";
        cout<<"The original string is: "<<my_name<<endl;
        //lets change a to A
        changeVar(my_name,'a',65);    
        cout<<"The changed string is: "<<my_name<<endl;

        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Using the reference to test ... "<<endl;
        cout<<endl;

        cout<<"The original string is: "<<my_name<<endl;
        //lets change a to A
        changeVar_refe(my_name,'a',65);    
        cout<<"The changed string is: "<<my_name<<endl;

        //cout <<"Char A is int 65:"<<int('A')<<endl;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks! The & makes sense but when I use it it gives me an output like this:

    ♣ * (2 + 3)

Instead of 5 * (2 + 3) for example.

Comment: `code`     //replace x inside x * (2 + 3) as 5*(2+3)
          // in ASCII representation, 5 is represented as 53
        string test_str = "x * (2 + 3)";
        changeVar_refe(test_str,'x',53); 
        cout<<test_str<<endl;`code`

Comment: try this: string test_str = "x * (2 + 3)"; changeVar_refe(test_str,'x',53); cout<<test_str<<endl;